# Getting an error because of primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

**Test**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Workershiftid       ShiftID        Startdate        EntityId      EndDate       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
149                   1     2016-08-01 00:00:00   1     2016-08-31 00:00:00 
150                   2     2016-08-01 00:00:00   4     2016-08-31 00:00:00 
151                   3     2016-08-01 00:00:00   5     2016-08-31 00:00:00 
152                   4     2016-08-01 00:00:00   7     2016-08-31 00:00:00 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am expecting the output like

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Workershiftid       ShiftID        Startdate        EntityId      EndDate       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
153                    1        2016-09-01 00:00:00   1     2016-09-31 00:00:00 
154                    2        2016-09-01 00:00:00   4     2016-09-31 00:00:00 
155                    3        2016-09-01 00:00:00   5     2016-09-31 00:00:00 
156                    4        2016-09-01 00:00:00   7     2016-09-31 00:00:00 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am running this query:

```
declare @start datetime
declare @end datetime

SELECT @start = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)
SELECT @end = DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0))

insert into test(workershiftid, shiftid, startdate, entityid, enddate)
    select 
        workershiftid, shiftid, @start, entityid, @end
    from 
        test
    where 
        startdate = '2016-08-01'
```

But I get an error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_M_AttendanceWorkerShift'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.M_AttendanceWorkerShift'.

I understand that workershiftid is primary key and it won't allow duplicates. I want to know how to fix this problem

Comment: Is WorkershiftID primary key with IDENTITY property? Post table create script

Comment: I create 1 dummy table also. USE [test1]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[mad1]    Script Date: 01-Sep-16 8:50:14 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mad1](
 [shiftid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [startdate] [smalldatetime] NULL,
 [enddate] [smalldatetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_mad1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [shiftid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

Comment: the script is different and doesn't match insert script. Update your question with create script of 'test' table.

Comment: SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test](
 [WorkerShiftID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [ShiftID] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [test_ShiftID]  DEFAULT ((0)),
 [StartDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
 [EntityID] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [test_EntityID]  DEFAULT ((0)),
 [EndDate] [smalldatetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [WorkerShiftID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

Comment: so you need just to remove workershiftid (which is PK with identity according to your script) from both INSERT and SELECT parts of your scripts. That value will be automatically populated by sql engine. Try it. If it works, I'll post it as answer. Also you have extra comma in ",," - you don't need it.

Comment: what exactly did you run?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122351/discussion-between-red-devil-and-anton).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have IDENTITY on PK (workershiftid)...

You need to remove workershiftid from the insert script, as sql server will automatically generate a new workershiftid for all the new rows

Final script:

```
insert into [dbo].[test](EntityID, startdate,shiftid, IsGroup, EndDate) 
 select EntityID,@start, shiftid, IsGroup, @end 
 from [dbo].[test] 
 where startdate='2016-08-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical way of fixing this problem is to declare the primary key column as an `identity` column and to let the database provide the value.  It then would not be included in the `update`.

Does that solution work for you?